# Синтаксическая ошибка

Tags: php

Обновил пост.

Вот новая ошибка

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in Z:\home\localhost\www\index.php on line 47

Вот 47 строка:

```
$postQ = 'email=' . $user . '@gmail.com&pass1=' . $password . '&pass2=' . $password . '&capcha=' . $otvet . '&reg=' . $ololo . ');
```

Где здесь ошибка?

Comment: Лишние ` . '` перед `');`

Учите матчасть PHP!

Comment: открывающую скобку не видно, зачем тогда здесь закрывающая?

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка `&lt;`. Это HTML-мнемоника символа "<".

Должно быть `for($i = 0; $i < $number; $i++)`

Comment: Обновил пост (скорее всего обновлю еще несколько раз (всего 67 строк))
Попробуй найти ошибку здесь, пожалуйста.

Comment: Вы издеваетесь?..

Comment: ну найди там ошибочку пожалуйста) писал на скорую руку, в пхп новичок

Comment: скиньте весь скрипт целиком, редактор и сервер под рукой

Comment: это единственная ошибка, которая осталась у меня

Answer (score 0):

странная строчка **$i < $number;**
никогда так не делал, и собственно вопрос, что она делает?)
ответ добавил - всё встало на свои места, **for($i = 0; $i < $number; $i++)**